# How to load more items and display in Listview builder by calling the Future in Flutter

Tags: flutter, scroll

How to load more items when scrolled and reached the end of the list. I am getting new page data by passing gcm value to my url but it does not append the list which is already existing instead it wipes out the existing data and displays new list.

Below is my code please help me if anyone can.

```
class Herbs extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  Herbs(this.title);

  @override
  _HerbsState createState() => new _HerbsState();
}

class _HerbsState extends State<Herbs> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  var cname;
  String gcm;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (gcm == null) {
      gcm = '';
      this.fetchPost(gcm);
    } else {
      this.fetchPost(gcm);
    }
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  _scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.offset >=
            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        print("reach the bottom");
        fetchPost(gcm);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<Herbslist> fetchPost(gcm) async {
    String url =
        'https://example.org/api.php?action=query&gcmtitle=Category:$cname&pilimit=max&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=200&generator=categorymembers&format=json&gcmcontinue=$gcm';
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = Herbslist.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      return data;
    } else {
      throw (e) {
        print("Exception thrown: $e");
        Exception(e);
      };
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    cname = widget.title;
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Align(
          alignment: Alignment(-0.2, 0.3),
          child: Text(
            cname,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<Herbslist>(
          future: fetchPost(gcm),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              List pages = snapshot.data.query.pages.values.toList();
              return Scrollbar(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: pages.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    gcm = snapshot.data.herbslistContinue.gcmcontinue;
                    var img = pages[index].thumbnail.source;
                    return Container(
                        child: Card(
                            child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => Detailpage(
                                pages[index].title,
                              ),
                            ));
                      },
                      child: ListTile(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 8.0),
                        leading: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              border: new Border(
                                  right: new BorderSide(
                                      width: 1.5, color: Colors.grey)),
                            ),
                            // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
                            child: img == img.isEmpty
                                ? SizedBox(
                                    height: 50.0,
                                    width: 50.0,
                                    child: Image.asset('images.png'),
                                  )
                                : SizedBox(
                                    height: 50.0,
                                    width: 50.0,
                                    child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                                      placeholder: 'images.png',
                                      image: img,
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                    ),
                                  )),
                        title: Text(pages[index].title),
                      ),
                    )));
                  },
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

JSON

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "continue": {
        "gcmcontinue": "page|41434143494120464552525547494e4541202d204152494d45444148|3704",
        "continue": "gcmcontinue||"
    },
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "225": {
                "pageid": 225,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Abrus precatorius - Gunja",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "source": "https://example.org/images/thumb/c/cb/Abrus_precatorius_%281463017430%29.jpg/600px-Abrus_precatorius_%281463017430%29.jpg",
                    "width": 600,
                    "height": 450
                },
                "pageimage": "Abrus_precatorius_(1463017430).jpg"
            },
            "625": {
                "pageid": 625,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Abies webbiana - Talispatra",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "source": "https://example.org/images/thumb/b/b1/Red_fir.jpg/397px-Red_fir.jpg",
                    "width": 397,
                    "height": 600
                },
                "pageimage": "Red_fir.jpg"
            },
            "15995": {
                "pageid": 15995,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Abelmoschus esculentus - Bhenda",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/India_-_Koyambedu_Market_-_Ladies_Finger_03_%283986242135%29.jpg/600px-India_-_Koyambedu_Market_-_Ladies_Finger_03_%283986242135%29.jpg",
                    "width": 600,
                    "height": 450
                },
                "pageimage": "India_-_Koyambedu_Market_-_Ladies_Finger_03_(3986242135).jpg"
            }
        }
    },
    "limits": {
        "pageimages": 500
    }
}
```

class.dart

```
class Herbslist {
    String batchcomplete;
    Continue herbslistContinue;
    Query query;
    Limits limits;

    Herbslist({
        this.batchcomplete,
        this.herbslistContinue,
        this.query,
        this.limits,
    });

    factory Herbslist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Herbslist(
        batchcomplete: json["batchcomplete"] == null ? null : json["batchcomplete"],
        herbslistContinue: json["continue"] == null ? Continue(gcmcontinue:'0',continueContinue: '') : Continue.fromJson(json["continue"]),
        query: json["query"] == null ? null : Query.fromJson(json["query"]),
        limits: json["limits"] == null ? null : Limits.fromJson(json["limits"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "batchcomplete": batchcomplete == null ? null : batchcomplete,
        "continue": herbslistContinue == null ? null : herbslistContinue.toJson(),
        "query": query == null ? null : query.toJson(),
        "limits": limits == null ? null : limits.toJson(),
    };
}

class Continue {
    String gcmcontinue;
    String continueContinue;

    Continue({
        this.gcmcontinue,
        this.continueContinue,
    });

    factory Continue.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Continue(
        gcmcontinue: json["gcmcontinue"] == null ? null : json["gcmcontinue"],
        continueContinue: json["continue"] == null ? null : json["continue"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "gcmcontinue": gcmcontinue == null ? null : gcmcontinue,
        "continue": continueContinue == null ? null : continueContinue,
    };
}

class Limits {
    int pageimages;

    Limits({
        this.pageimages,
    });

    factory Limits.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Limits(
        pageimages: json["pageimages"] == null ? null : json["pageimages"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "pageimages": pageimages == null ? null : pageimages,
    };
}

class Query {
    Map<String, Page> pages;

    Query({
        this.pages,
    });

    factory Query.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Query(
        pages: json["pages"] == null ? null : Map.from(json["pages"]).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, Page>(k, Page.fromJson(v))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "pages": pages == null ? null : Map.from(pages).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
    };
}

class Page {
    int pageid;
    int ns;
    String title;
    Thumbnail thumbnail;
    String pageimage;

    Page({
        this.pageid,
        this.ns,
        this.title,
        this.thumbnail,
        this.pageimage,
    });

    factory Page.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Page(
        pageid: json["pageid"] == null ? null : json["pageid"],
        ns: json["ns"] == null ? null : json["ns"],
        title: json["title"] == null ? null : json["title"],
        thumbnail: json["thumbnail"] == null ? Thumbnail(source:'',width:0,height:0) : Thumbnail.fromJson(json["thumbnail"]),
        pageimage: json["pageimage"] == null ? null : json["pageimage"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "pageid": pageid == null ? null : pageid,
        "ns": ns == null ? null : ns,
        "title": title == null ? null : title,
        "thumbnail": thumbnail == null ? null : thumbnail.toJson(),
        "pageimage": pageimage == null ? null : pageimage,
    };
}

class Thumbnail {
    String source;
    int width;
    int height;

    Thumbnail({
        this.source,
        this.width,
        this.height,
    });

    factory Thumbnail.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Thumbnail(
        source: json["source"] == null ? null : json["source"],
        width: json["width"] == null ? null : json["width"],
        height: json["height"] == null ? null : json["height"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "source": source == null ? null : source,
        "width": width == null ? null : width,
        "height": height == null ? null : height,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Make these changes and try:**

```
class _HerbsState extends State<Herbs> {
  List pages;  // add this
  ....
```

**Next:**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    pages = []; // add this
    if (gcm == null) {
      gcm = '';
      this.fetchPost(gcm);
    } else {
      this.fetchPost(gcm);
    }
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }
```

**Finally:**

```
FutureBuilder<Herbslist>(
          future: fetchPost(gcm),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              List pages = snapshot.data.query.pages.values.toList(); // remove this line

              pages.addAll(snapshot.data.query.pages.values); // add this line
              ...
```

Comment: This fixed my issue thank you so much.I was stuck for a week.

Comment: Hey, Scrolling is okay but I am getting the repeated list. If I get pageno-1's list and when I scroll it again shows the pageno-1's list and again when scrolled it loads the pageno-2's list and when we reach the end of the list it again loads pageno-2's list and so on. Please can you help me in in this issue.